# cannot find authoritative source location for XSOM

Tags: java, xsom

I'm looking for the official source code for XSOM. What with the various openJDK moves from an HG server to github, and splitting out of J2EE stuff from rest of OpenJDK, and the sheer volume of forks on github, I'm simply not finding it via searching. I can find lots of unofficial forks and such.

I hope to fix a bug, or at least better understand what XSOM is doing wrong with elementFormDefault and element form information. A fix here, or better understanding of what is actually happening in XSOM, is essential for mapping XML Schema information to w3c semantic web in the Ontmalizer tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, I think this is it: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri

Long answer:

Archive.org has some information about XSOM being hosted on java.net as
part of the glassfish project:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110219005858/http://java.net:80/projects/xsom/sources/sources/show/trunk

At some point things were migrated away from java.net:

http://www.oracle.com/splash/java.net/maintenance/index.html

But XSOM isn't listed in any of those. Looking at maven central for xsom
finds this:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/xsom/2.4.0-b180830.0438/jar

Which is glassfish, so it seems xsom is now part of glassfish jaxb. The
repo for that is here:

https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2

And that does contains this xsom directory:

https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/tree/master/jaxb-ri/xsom

And src/main/java does have the original com/sun/xml/xsom package name.
The commit logs also show evidence that xsom was merged into this jaxb-v2 repo.

https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/commit/fe70e9210e316017ecccb1cf866ffae48927393c

The README for that repo has a notice that has migrated to this repo:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri

Which does have documentation about jaxb-ri/xsom. So I believe that is where the original java.net XSOM ended up with active development.